# ASP.NET MVC4 DropDownListFor is not showing the selected value from the DataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

In one of our ASP.NET MVC 4 views, we have a DropDownListFor (along with other html controls) as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ProductType,
                      (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductType,
                      "--- Select Product Type ----")
```

The list is getting populated from a database lookup table. When we click on the submit button, all the controls values including the selected value of the dropdownlist get inserted into the database successfully. But when the page is displayed the dropdown's selected value always shows "--- Select Product Type ----" instead of the value that was inserted into the database.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the selected value in your SelectList inside your Controller i.e. ViewBag.ProductType.

Have a look at the overloads for SelectList class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    var items = db.ProductType.ToList();
    var selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(x => get desired selected item);

    ViewBag.ProductType = 
        new SelectList(items, "ProductID", "ProductType",  selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: we are using the following in the controller `ViewBag.ProductType = db.ProductType.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ProductID.ToString(), Value = x.ProductType, Selected=true }).ToList();`. But it still does not work. If I use the SelectList as in you example, I get the error `The name SelectedValue does not exist in the current contenct`.

Comment: Updated answer. You are setting Selected=true for ALL your items which is incorrect.

Comment: on the line 'var items = ..' and the line 'var selectedItem = ..', I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.